# ngx-datatable (select) action doesn't re-render count of rows selected

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am trying to display the number of items selected on the table; when I first load the page everything works as it should, but as soon as I scroll to the bottom then back up again, clicking on a checkbox doesn't update the string-interpolated display of number of rows clicked. The only way for it to display correctly is to move my cursor down a few items and then it will update properly.

TS Snippet

```
public onRowSelected(eventObject) {
const realTasks: Array<Task> = filter(eventObject['selected'], (rawTask: Task) => {
  return rawTask.isTask;
});
this.numSelectedTasks = realTasks.length;
this.taskSelected.emit(realTasks);
console.log(this.numSelectedTasks);
```

}

HTML Snippet

```
      <span class="text-bold text-primary" 
           *ngIf="selectable">{{ numSelectedTasks}} Tasks Selected. </span>
```